# AngularJs-share object array between directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to send an array of objects from parent directive to child directive but i am getting console.log($scope.$eval(attrs.model)) as undefined .

```
angular.module('tester').directive('gChart',gChart);
    function gChart() {

        var template = getTemplate;
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: "^Logs",
            replace:true,
            template: template,
            scope:{
                model: "="
            },
            link: function($scope, $element, attrs, LogsCtrl) {
                console.log($scope.$eval(attrs.model));
                LogsCtrl.show($scope.$eval(attrs.model));
            }
        };

        function getTemplate() {
            return'<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height:             500px;margin: 0px auto;"></div>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I would use factory and inject that factory in both directive. Sharing as per coding standard in angular should be done via factory. It will make ur life easy. If u need any help with that let me know but use factory to share data between controller and directive make application more testable also

Comment: I use a service to share that data, do you have a link I can reference to see the best practice labeled as a factory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post all of your code for us to understand. Besides, your array of data should be in `$scope.model`, and not in the `attrs.model`. This is because you define the scope of your directive as

```
scope:{
    model: "="
},
```

So, in your html, you should have something like:

```
<tester model="YOUR_DATA" ></tester>
```